# Remove an object from a List without removing the entire List

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, realm

```
[2] Flow {
        name =  flow;
        id = 2;
        imgName = ;
        slides = RLMArray <0x7ff22a831ab0> (
            [0] Slide {
                name = nuevo slide;
                imgName = ;
                reference = ;
                id = 0;
            },
            [1] Slide {
                name = nuevo slide;
                imgName = ;
                reference = ;
                id = 0;
            }
        );
```

Hi, I have an object called FLOW containing an array of objects SLIDE type, I want to remove one of the objects entered into this array and so far the only thing I've seen is that you can remove the entire array, but that did not interest me, I want to remove only some of the objects within the array, any help is good, thanks

UPDATE:I found a simple way to do this and is accessing the array of slides from the object flow on which want to interact

```
internal func deleteSlideFromFlow(flow:Flow,slide:Slide){

        try! realm.write{
            flow.slides.realm?.delete(slide)
        }
}
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Your question makes no sense, sorry

Comment: makes sense, another thing is that you do not understand;)

Answer (score -1):

have you tried something like this?

```
Flow {
  name =  flow;
  id = 2;
  imgName = "";
  var slides = NSMutableArray();

    func insertSlide(slide:Slide, index:Int){
       self.slides.insertObject(slide, atIndex: index);
    }

    func removeSlideAtIndex(index:Int){
       self.slides.removeObjectAtIndex(index);
    }

    func removeSlide(slide:Slide){
       self.slides.removeObject(slide);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider structuring your code, it is not readable atm

Comment: thanks, finally found a simpler way
internal func deleteSlideFromFlow(flow:Flow,slide:Slide){
        
        try! realm.write{
            flow.slides.realm?.delete(slide)
        }
    }